# There is no publisher option in wowza streamingengine under server tab

Tags: wowza

I have installed wowza streaming engine when I clicked in that it takes me to [here](http://localhost:8088/enginemanager/Home.htm#home/_defaultVHost_).

I have given `userid` and `password` then navigate to `server` tab under `User`. I had to add `publisher`, but it seems there is no `publisher` option?
Any idea where to get the `publisher`? Or is there any alternate is there for `publisher` in the new version of wowza streaming engine?

Here I am attached the screen shot:[image]

**Note:** I am using wowza streaming engine version **4.4.1**

Answer (score 1):

The Server > Users page (`*/enginemanager/Home.htm#server/_defaultVHost_/serverusers`) is for adding users to administrate the WSE server.

To add publishers, you should use the Server > Source Authentication page (`*/enginemanager/Home.htm#server/_defaultVHost_/serverpublishers`).